Update string after second white space from left in SQl Server
I have this type of value in table column (cron expressions):
0 0 14? * MON *
0 0 12? * FRI *
0 0 121 * ? *
0 0 01 OCT ? 2099
0 10 13? * * *
I want to add +1 to third number (in this example: 14, 12, 12, 0, and 13). I need this values (in SQl):
0 0 15? * MON *
0 0 13? * FRI *
0 0 131 * ? *
0 0 11 OCT ? 2099
0 10 14? * * *

Are the ** here just an attempt to apply bolding to those elements to highlight them or do they exist in the data? Do you have any where the hour component is anything other than a single integer? Do you have any where the hour component is 23?

A combination of STRING_AGG and STRING_SPLIT (using the new ordinal column) and a bit of conversions should do the trick.
UPDATE YourTable
SET cron = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
      IIF(s.ordinal = 3, CONVERT(varchar(15), TRY_CONVERT(int, s.value) + 1), s.value),
      ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.ordinal)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(cron, ' ', 1) s
  )

db<>fiddle

If the value is 23, this will generate a wrong expression.

OP did not specify that it had to rollover, or that any of their data was a problem regarding that, but that can be solved easily by adding ) % 24 to the calculation.
